# Java/SQL String manipulation to make "Foo".equals("Bar???")

Tags: java, sql, regex, string

I've got this puzzle from my lecturer

```
public class Exercise{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int foo = 10;
        assert("Foo".equals("Bar???"));
    }
}
```

I'm supposed to add something at ??? and that will be the only place I'm allowed to write.
I've been thinking and googling for more than 2 days but still haven't got any clues at all.

It is Java obviously but the puzzle's name is SQLInjection and that's why I think it might be related to SQL.

I strongly think I'm supposed to use regex since that's the only thing I can think of that could be written inside a String. Also I'm not sure what is that int foo doing in the code.

Any thoughts or hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: `".substring(0, 0)+"Foo`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the `???` with `".substring(0, 0)+"Foo` and you get:

```
    assert("Foo".equals("Bar".substring(0, 0)+"Foo"));
```

This is not an SQL injection, but it is *similar* to SQL injection (only with Java instead of SQL, and you are filling in the code manually instead of having a program do it).

Comment: I see. Thank you very much. I thought I could only write inside the String and that is where I was wrong!

Answer (score 3):

You could use the fact that String literals are interned so `==` will give true when comparing their references:

replace `???` by `") || ("" == "` which yields in

```
assert("Foo".equals("Bar") || ("" == ""));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can improve level of difficulty. Lets say that our task is to replace `???` in this code

```
assert("Foo".equals("Bar???") && userAccessLevel==Access.Admin);
```

to make it always work.

You can do it by changing it to

```
assert("Foo".equals("Bar") || true);//") && userAccessLevel==Access.Admin);
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

so as you see

- we can remove some conditions by simply commenting rest of code in that line,
- this way our `"` don't have to be even balanced in replacement part `") || true);//`.
- we don't need to know *correct* (expected) value `"Foo"` because we are setting result of validation simply by placing `|| true`.

Comment: I think this is more in the spirit of the question, +1

Answer (score 0):

Some additional solutions.

```
assert("Foo".equals("BarFoo".replace("Bar", "") + ""));
assert("Foo".equals("Bar".equals("Foo") ? "Bar" : "Foo"));
assert("Foo".equals("Bar.Foo".split("\\.")[1] + ""));
```

**edit this doesn't fulfil the requirement** I leave it for the record.

If you are allowed to use reflection you could do it like this

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
public class Exercise {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Field value = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
        // make a private field accessible
        value.setAccessible(true);
        // set the value of the interned String "Foo" to "Bar???"
        value.set("Foo", "Bar???".toCharArray());

        // as this String literal referes to the same object
        // as in the source code before "Foo" was replaced by "Bar???" ;-)
        boolean equals = "Foo".equals("Bar???");
        System.out.println("equals: " + equals);

        // would fail with an java.lang.AssertionError
        // if the assertion is not true
        assert("Foo".equals("Bar???"));
    }
}
```

**compile**

```
javac Excercise.java
```

**run**

```
java -ea Excercise
```

Comment: _"I'm supposed to add something at ??? and that will be the only place I'm allowed to write"_

Comment: You're right. My answer doesn't fulfil the requirement. Haven't paid attention on this.

Answer (score 0):

".substring(0, 0)+"Foo

This is the correct syntax for the answer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).